# Ext.ux.StoreMenu cannot add to container

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu, containers, store

I dynamically create an `ext.ux.StoreMenu` but no mather what I try it doesn't get renderes to my container. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
onStoreLoadeded{
var container = this.getMenuContainer();


var menu1 = Ext.create('Ext.ux.menu.StoreMenu', {
        store: store,
        itemsHandler: function(item, evt) {
            Ext.example.msg("First Menu Store", "You click on item with id " + item.id);
        },
    renderTo: document.body
    });


container.add(menu1);
container.doLayout();
}
```

The container is present I have checked that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

> > container.removeAll();
> >
> > container.add(menu1);
> >
> > container.doLayout();

Comment: Sorry it did not help!